# Highcharts set slice size of pie chart

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, pie-chart

Is possible to change size of a slice of pie chart?

Ex: Need to change this black slice of a certain value or percentage.

This slice represents 10% of the pie, need to change to 1% for example.

[image]

Comment: Hi @sealabr, Could you describe your problem more precisely? Each slice in the chart represents one data point.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `update()` function to the point you want to modify : [Highcharts Point update](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point.html#update)

`chart.series[0].data[0].update({y: 14});`